# Looping through user input and inserting into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a script that will ask a user for input and then insert their response into a dict.

So far I have been able to get 1 key/value but am confused on how I am able to continually ask for input over and over again...

```
number = int(input('How many student\'s do you have in your class? '))

name = raw_input('Please input your student\'s name. ')
grade = raw_input('What is the student\'s final grade? ')

for n in range(number):
    usr_input[name] = [grade]

for k,v in usr_input.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

I am aiming to understand how I can have the script continuously ask for input based off what the user answers to 'number'. For instance, if the user answers '5' as the number of students. How can I get the script to ask the user for 5 student's names and their respective grade?

Comment: Just simply move those two lines `name = raw_input('Please input your student\'s name. ')
grade = raw_input('What is the student\'s final grade? ')` into `for n in range(number):` this for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your `name` and `grade` inputs under your `for` statement:

```
for n in range(number):
    name = raw_input('Please input your student\'s name. ')
    grade = raw_input('What is the student\'s final grade? ') 
    usr_input[name] = [grade]
```

Then, for each iteration of the `for` loop, two inputs will be retrieved from the user and added to your dictionary as a key-value pair.